# CKAN Set user permissions

Tags: ckan, paster

After installing a fresh copy of CKAN 2.5a I want to give admin privileges for some users over a given organization.

Reading http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-1.7.2/paster.html#rights-set-user-permissions looks like there is a paster command "rights" with this purpose, but is not known in my env. (running paster --plugin=ckan --help I get all the available commands and certainly it is not there)

Is this command deprecated in CKAN 2.5a? There is maybe another way to assign rights to on user over a given object?

Any help or guidance would be appreciated

Comment: Just some minutes after writing the question I got the answer. The authorization system changed after 2.0 more information here: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/authorization.html

Comment: You can post the answer to your questions and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Rights was deprecated in the migration to CKAN 2.X. You can do an API call to organization_update, passing in the existing organization information and dictionary which contains a list of user names and roles to assign membership and roles to your users.